# why is nsmanaged object returning nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject

I am testing to see if a flag is set before performing a segue. I log the output and the selected object is nil,  and I don't understand why. I can see all the cells properly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

It's probably something obvious but I can't see it..

Code is this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender];

    id object;
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        object = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        indexPath = [self.objectTable indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender];
        object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }

    NSLog(@"object is: %@", object);
```

Any ideas welcome.. If you need more code, please ask.

Comment: nil comes from searchResults or fetchedResultsController? is indexPath = [self.objectTable .... == nil?

Comment: Which path does your code go through - the if or the else? Does searchResults contain anything?

Comment: Thanks Guys.. the code is going through the FetchedResultsController  path, so that is nil. Why? It was fine when I listed the cells. +1 each for helping

Comment: What is `sender`?  Is `sender` an instance of a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: It should be an instance of a custom tableView cell. Do you think that's a problem?

Comment: I've changed the code to refer directly to the custom cell instead of UITableViewCell. Still same result..

Comment: @Paulw11 - you nailed it.. I had a few references to UITableViewCell - instead of my custom cell. All is well now. If you write this up as an answer, I'll credit you...